# Awk/ Perl regular expression to match space with hyphen

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I have the following 2 lines in sample.txt

```
AIA - 1000
AIA Integrations for E-Business Suite - 5544
```

Now i want to see the following output:

```
Column1                                         | Column2
AIA                                               1000
AIA Integrations for E-Business Suite             5544
```

i tried:

```
awk -F "-" sample.txt
```

It filters the hyphen "-" near "E-Business Suite"
How to make it filter the last hyphen instead of the intermediate ones.

Comment: Use: `awk -F " - " ... `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -F ' - ' -v OFS=';' 'BEGIN{print "Column1", "Column2"} {print $1, $2}' file |
column -s ';' -t

Column1                                Column2
AIA                                    1000
AIA Integrations for E-Business Suite  5544
```

- `-F ' - '` uses `" - "` is input field separator
- `-v OFS=';'` uses `;` as output field separator
- `column -s ';' -t` formats data in tabular format using `;` as delimiter

Comment: As a final add-up, can you let us know how to add the header part (assuming it is needed) dynamically based on the longest value using `BEGIN`? Using `column` looks simpler. But just wanted to know if it is possible.

Comment: @Inian: Added header row as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use perl to guarentee that we are truly catching the last `-` as the separator not some other instance of it in the middle of the first field:

```
perl -wnle '/^(.+) - (.+)$/ or die; print "$1\t$2"' sample.txt
```

If you want the output to be in fixed width columns, you can use `column`:

```
perl -wnle '/^(.+) - (.+)$/ or die; print "$1\t$2"' sample.txt | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Explanation: The first `(.+)` in the regex will capture the first group. Because `+` is greedy, `^(.+) -` it match with the largest possible substring, so that if there are multiple instances of `-`, it will include all of them but the last one in the first capture group. Then the last `(.+)` will capture all the remaining characters in the second capture group.

Comment: You can fix this by adding the /s modifier to the regex.

Comment: @RichardRP I fixed it now, I had forgotten the `\n` at the end of the print (an `/s` would have also worked).

Comment: Why are you capturing after the `-`, there is no need. Also you can use the  `-l` flag to preserve newlines.

Comment: @123 The `-l` does indeed shorten my answer by one character (`l` vs `\n`), but makes the code less readable, which is why I did not use it initially. I changed it now. As for why I am capturing after the `-`, doesn't the OP want both fields?

Comment: @redneb you are replacing the `-`, redundant to capture afterwards. How is `-l` less readable? Whole thing could be reduced to `perl -lpe 's/(.+) -/$1\t/'`

Comment: @123 I am capturing the 2 fields, left and right of ` - ` , I am not doing a substitution here. I guess I could have used something like `s/.+\K - /\t/` with `-p` instead of `-n`. As for `-l`, I use it with my one-liners, but I guessed that a `\n` in a print would be less scary for someone who doesn't know perl.

Answer (score 0):

Another example, using split and join:

```
perl -F- -e 'print join "\t", reverse pop @F, join "-", @F' sample.txt
```